# caching of subquery in oracle always returning same values ?

Tags: oracle, cursor, subquery

As shown in the below cursor definition , the subquery in the where clause always returns the same values , for each unique value of (a1,p1) , does oracle perform caching on these the values  , or is the subquery executed each time the outer query is executed , note here the query is executed inside a parameterized cursor.

```
cursor cur(a1 , p1)  
is
  select a , b  
  from table1 
  where a = a1
  and b in (select p from table2 where q = p1);
```

Comment: There may be caching involved, but on a technical level. If there is a - commited - change anywhere in the database, that would cause the subquery to cause different data to be selected, that new data will be provided. Oracle is very correct on that part: if new data is commited, you will get the new data. Bad caching of data, as which is common on webservers, where they continue to get old data on your screen, even though the data on the server has changed (which is caused by the browser), that, does not occur with Oracle databases. Unless ... YOU have an uncommited session yourself.

Comment: is there someway to force oracle to use the old data from subquery and not refresh the cache ?